# Docking Asus Transformer Prime back-to-front?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, docking-station

Is it possible to dock the tablet in a sort of "back-to-front" way such that if I were to close the tablet whilst docked, the front screen would be facing up?

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally confused: No, I don't think the tablet will turn around when you are getting close... Errm, surely that's not what you meant -- so maybe you can re-phrase your question to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me try again.

Suppose I have the tablet docked, facing it I have the keyboard in front of me and the screen.

I've seen somewhere that I can turn the screen around such that it is back to front... Reversed, so when I close it, the front screen is at the top and the rear of the screen rests on the keyboard. I've seen it before but only once...

I just want to verify this before I buy.

Answer (score 2):

No, the tablet only fits into the Transfomer keyboard/dock one way, with the screen closed against the keyboard when folded shut.